# How to access a variable inside an anguljarjs service from a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs `service`, that holds a `model` property for the frontend binding.

I also want to create a `function` that processes some input data and updates the model accordingly:

```
angular.module('test').service('testService', testService);
function testService() {
    return {
        model: [
            mylist = null
        ],

        setMyList: setMyList
    };

    function setMyList(data) {
        //process data
        mylist = data; //error: "model is not defined"
    }
}
```

from any controller:

```
testService.setMyList(data);
```

Problem: the function cannot see the model. Why, and how could I change this?

Comment: make a closure of `model` array and return it.

Comment: Could you give an example on this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

```
var model: {
            mylist = null
};

return {
    model: model,
    setMyList: setMyList
}

function setMyList(data)...
```